# CXF Jaxb Marshalling : Degraded Performance

Tags: jaxb, cxf

I am using CXF : JAXB for my WebServices. The typical output xml size is 7-8mb. While trying to do a load testing I discoverd that when there is close to 30-concurrent service's being requested through the application the CXF part where I guess only marshalling would be happening takes close to 30-35seconds this is after when the application part gets completed .

Application -> CXF

I am using the default stuff for enabling the marshaling part. Version of JAXB is (jaxb-impl-2.1.3.jar,jaxb-api-2.1.jar ) and CXF is 2.3.2 .

I came to know this latency when I started sending out a empty xml response as compared to a full response while still running through the application part where I saw the diff was around 30-35 seconds.

How could I fix this : would changing the parser for JAXB eg SAX,Stax would help.

Comment: I actually have woodstox and sax in my classpath as well. I think it should take woodstox for XMLOutputfactory . will get it validated anyways